# How does Intel Xeon processor do subtraction?

Tags: cpu, intel, processor, alu

I can think of the following approaches:

1. Use a adder. For A-B, first compute `-B`'s two's complement. Then add `A`'s two's complement with `-B`'s two's complement.
2. Use a subtractor like [Adder–subtractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor).

Which approach does Intel Xeon use? If Intel Xeon does not use any of the above approaches, what else approach does Intel Xeon use?

Comment: I think it just uses a `SUB` instruction.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The question is asking about the underlying hardware, not the instruction set.

Comment: @user4098326: I was being facetious.

Comment: There is no point in propagating the one added to the bitwise inverted number to form its twos complement and then doing a second propagation for the addition, *especially* when the ISA supports add with carry so a carry-in for the first bit is required anyway.

Comment: **Intel Xeon** could mean a processor from 1998.  Or a processor from 2015.  For which processor do you want an answer?

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson: A processor from 2015 such as Xeon E7.

Comment: I believe such info is proprietary and you won't find it anywhere public :-)